# How does Webix implement hidden text controls to enforce rules

Tags: javascript, webix

There is a hidden `text` control in the project requirement. The text is assigned by the result of the `file upload`, but the hidden control does not seem to be monitored by the Rule rule.
The sample is as follows

```
App.form={
    elements:[
        ....
        ,{"cols": [
                {id: "file_code", name: "file_code", view: "text", invalidMessage:"please upload file", hidden: true},
                {id: "file_code_btn", view: "button", label: "select file", "width": 100, "inputHeight": 20},
            ]}
    ],
    rules:{
        "name": webix.rules.isNotEmpty
        ,"file_code": webix.rules.isNotEmpty
    }
```

When I change the `hidden property` to false, I can realize the non-null check in the front end, but it cannot be realized after the hidden property.

I would appreciate it if you could tell me how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

By default hidden and disabled fields are ignored during data validation.
Though, you can add an extra parameter to the `validate` call to include them

```js
form.validate({ hidden: true })
```

https://docs.webix.com/desktop__data_validation.html#validationofhiddenanddisabledfieldsinform